# sum over multiple columns by group

Tags: r, data.table

How can I sum multiple columns by group please?

For the following data I can get the expected result using base r split-apply functions:

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
df1 = data.table(grp = sample(0:2, 10, TRUE), 
                 a=sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), b=sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), 
                 c=sample(0:1, 10, TRUE), d=sample(0:1, 10, TRUE))
df1
#     grp a b c d
#  1:   1 1 1 1 0
#  2:   1 1 0 0 0
#  3:   0 0 1 1 0
#  4:   2 1 1 1 0
#  5:   0 1 1 0 1
#  6:   0 1 0 1 1
#  7:   1 1 1 0 1
#  8:   1 1 0 1 1
#  9:   2 1 0 1 1
# 10:   1 1 0 1 0

rbindlist(lapply(split(df1, df1$grp), 
                    function(x) as.data.table(t(colSums(x[,-1])))), idcol="grp")
#    grp a b c d
# 1:   0 2 2 2 2
# 2:   1 5 2 3 2
# 3:   2 2 1 2 1
```

How to do this with `data.table` syntax?

These attempts do not give the expected outcome:

```r
df1[, .(s = lapply(.SD, sum)), .SDcols=a:d, by=grp]
df1[, .(s = colSums(.SD)), .SDcols=a:d, by=grp]
```

Comment: `df1[, lapply(.SD, sum), .SDcols=a:d, by=grp]`

Comment: sheesh, thank Ronak; don't know what I was doing by assigning a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df1[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(grp), .SDcols = c("a", "b", "c", "d")]
#    grp a b c d
# 1:   1 5 2 3 2
# 2:   0 2 2 2 2
# 3:   2 2 1 2 1
```

I used the programmatic mode of columns determination (`c(...)`) with the guess that you might need to produce them dynamically, e.g., `setdiff(colnames(df1), "grp")`. If that's not needed, you can use RonakShah's recommendation of `a:d` as well.